# sorting data based on month and date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

My db structure is following:

```
long OccasionId { get; set; }
string OccasionName { get; set; }
string OccasionDesc { get; set; }
DateTime OccasionDate { get; set; }
```

I need my result on html in following format

```
February
     OccasionName1
     5th February
     OccasionDesc1

     OccasionName2
     7th February
     OccasionDesc2
```

Now the data has to be sorted and grouped by month and then date but not year; means  if there are two dates 05/02/1974 and 07/02/1970, even though the second date comes first because of the year, I need the sorting to be such that 5th feb comes first.

I'm using entity framework and asp.net mvc

Thanks

Arnab

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't mention your DB, but on SQL Server:

```
var q = from o in Context.Occasions
        orderby o.Month, o.Day
        select o;
```

...should work. Did you try that? However, it may or may not be efficient depending on the particulars of the rest of the query.

Comment: tx,this I have already done but this gives me data sorted which does not solve my problem, I need help with the frontend code which would iterate through the data and show the data in the specified format.

Comment: someone said I need to do a groupby month and then orderby date, but won't that make the result a list of lists, any ideas??